# pass unordered_set as initialization list through packed parameters

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass initialization list to unordered_set through packed parameter but doesn't work. See below code, calling Foo works but Add with compiler error. Does C++ support such syntax? Thanks

```
class Foo {
public:
 Foo(std::unordered_set<int>&& input) : input_ids_{std::forward<std::unordered_set<int>>(input)} {

  }
 private:
  std::unordered_set<int> input_ids_;
};

template<typename... Args>
void Add(Args&&... args) {
  auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() 
{
  // Ok
  Foo({1, 2, 3});
  
  //Compiler error
  Add({1, 2, 3});
}

g++ test1.cc
test1.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test1.cc:36:16: error: too many arguments to function ‘void Add(Args&& ...) [with Args = {}]’
   36 |   Add({1, 2, 3});
      |                ^
test1.cc:26:6: note: declared here
   26 | void Add(Args&&... args) {
      |      ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/memory:83,
                 from test1.cc:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = Foo; _Args = {}; typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::default_delete<Foo> >]’:
test1.cc:27:35:   required from ‘void Add(Args&& ...) [with Args = {}]’
test1.cc:36:16:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/unique_ptr.h:962:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo()’
  962 |     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test1.cc:18:2: note: candidate: ‘Foo::Foo(std::unordered_set<int>&&)’
   18 |  Foo(std::unordered_set<int>&& input) : input_ids_{std::forward<std::unordered_set<int>>(input)} {
      |  ^~~
test1.cc:18:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test1.cc:16:7: note: candidate: ‘Foo::Foo(const Foo&)’
   16 | class Foo {
      |       ^~~
test1.cc:16:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test1.cc:16:7: note: candidate: ‘Foo::Foo(Foo&&)’
test1.cc:16:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: There are [three places where `std::initializer_list` is deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list): (1) When passed as an initializer for an object that supports `initializer_list` initialization; (2) when passed as an assignment or parameter to a function that supports `initializer_list`; (3) when bound to `auto`. Note that variadic parameters do not fall into any of the above cases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler cannot deduce the type of the template parameter as a `std::initializer_list` from the information provided.  To fix this, just tell it:

```
Add(std::initializer_list <int> {1, 2, 3});
```

---

**Edit:** So why can't the compiler deduce the type of the template parameter?  Well. I think it's because `std::initializer_list` is not really a proper type.  The following compiles OK:

```
class Foo {
public:
 Foo(int x) : x_ (x) {

  }
 public:
  int x_;
};

template<typename... Args>
void Add(Args&&... args) {
  auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  std::cout << foo->x_;
}

int main() 
{
  // OK
  Foo(1);

  // OK 
  Add(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use std::initializer_list, it is just ugly. Btw, I don't see why it can't deduce it.

Comment: No, I don't have enough template-fu to know that either.

Comment: ... but I think it's because `std::initialiser_list` is not really a proper type, see addition to my answer.